# Identifying a substitution cipher random key. (English text)

Tags: cryptography, encryption

input:
Crypted English normal text (A-Z) using a random generated substitution cipher.

output: 
key

ideas:
read the whole text storing in some arrays the frequencies for each character/bigram/trigram and comparing them to:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequencies
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigram

cons: letters/bigrams/trigrams with close percentage (like "c" and "u")

my software should be able to guess the max. possible characters from the crypted text (minimum 2000 characters).
I have to guess at least 18-20 letters.

**questions:**
is there a way/known algorithm to guess all the characters => full key ?
or can you give me some useful references or advices on how I could improve the whole guessing process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track.  The only way you could recover the full key would be if the all characters (or all-1) are present in the plain text.

I'd be thinking along the lines of making some statistical guesses and then statictically checking the results for the plaintext Bigrams/Trigrams which result.  Or checking whole words (if you know where the word boundaries are) against a word list.

Comment: That's a problem.. I have only letters from A to Z without spaces.. and the last letter from 1 word + first letter from the next word would form a digram in my statistics.. I was wondering if the frequencies found on wikipedia would work for me.

Comment: As long as it's a 26-character key you're looking for having 26 characters in the text is okay.  My point is that if the plain-text doesn't include the letters Q, X & Z, for example, you won't be able to determine the substitutions for those characters.  Not knowing the word boundaries probably will screw up the digram statistics.